Unable to install tensorflow 2.16 with GPU support
I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu 24. I tried to install the last TensorFlow with GPU support, but TensorFlow could not find the GPU. To do that, I used Miniconda and noticed I could not install CUDA 12.3. Also, I have to install 8.9, but looking at the cuDNN website, the last version of supported Ubuntu is 22 instead of the 24 I’m using. Can someone provide me with a step-by-step guide on how to install TensorFlow on Ubuntu?

HI@nathaldien,Make sure your GPU is CUDA-enabled and compatible with TensorFlow. You can check TensorFlow's official documentation for supported GPUs.First, you need to install the appropriate NVIDIA GPU drivers for your GPU model. You can do this through Ubuntu's Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates, or via command line:'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall'.TensorFlow requires a specific version of CUDA Toolkit. As of now, TensorFlow 2.8.x typically requires CUDA 11.2. Go to the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit download page and download the appropriate runfile installer for Ubuntu.

Always check the official TensorFlow installation guide.
